# Pasar variable ajax a php y como realizar el llamado en php

Tags: php, java, ajax

Hola tengo el siguiente problema tengo un  select dinamico que le da al los usuario una opcion y dependiendo de esa opcion arroja otras opciones son 2 select este es el codigo

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Cantidad de coolers
            <select id="cantidad" name="cantidad" class="form-control">
            </select>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <p>Coolers
          <select id="coolers" name="coolers" class="form-control">
          </select>
        </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <p><br><button id="enviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Enviar</button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <p><b>El resultado es: </b></p><p id="seleccion"></p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

esta selecion funciona con un codigo AJAX que almacenas los valores selecionados y luego los devuelve al html este es el codigo ajax

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'cargar_listas.php'
    })

    .done(function(listas_rep){
      $('#cantidad').html(listas_rep)
    })

    .fail(function(){

      alert('Hubo un errror al cargar las listas_rep')
    })


    $('#cantidad').on('change', function(){

      var id = $('#cantidad').val()

   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'cargar_coolers.php',
        data: {'id': id}
      })

      .done(function(listas_rep){

        $('#coolers').html(listas_rep)
      })

      .fail(function(){

        alert('Hubo un errror al cargar los vídeos')
      })
    })

    $('#enviar').on('click', function(){

      var resultado = 'Cantidad: ' + $('#cantidad option:selected ').text() +
      ' Coolers elegido: ' + $('#coolers option:selected').text()

      $('#resultado1').html(resultado);

      $.post("envio.php", {"resultado":resultado});
    });

  });
```

ahora bien el Select y el ajax funcionan perfectamente ya que la al final se imprime por pantalla los valores selecionados

Ahora mi problema es el siguiente yo quiero tomar los Valores que se imprimen por pantalla por medio de AJAX en un ID y pasarlos a una variable php para almacenar o usar ese valor en otro lado

en este caso la variable que almacena los valores se llama (resultado)

```
  var resultado = 'Cantidad: ' + $('#cantidad option:selected ').text() +
      ' Coolers elegido: ' + $('#coolers option:selected').text()
```

y el ID donde se almacena la variable se llama #resultado1

ahora yo utilizo este codigo en ajax para enviar la variable a php

```
  $.post("envio.php", {"resultado":resultado});
```

y en la url envio.php llamo la variable de este modo

```
  <?php

    echo $_GET['resultado'];

  ?>
```

ahora mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para pasar la variable de ajax resultado a php y si la estoy pasando bien como la llamo en envio.php

gracias espero a ver sido claro

Answer (score 0):

Tenés un error en el encomillado, probá con:

```
$.post( "envio.php", {resultado:resultado});
```

y en envío.php deberías poder leerla con:

```
$resultado = $_POST["resultado"]
```

Comment: hola pedro ya lo corregi y no funciona me sigue diciendo   Notice: Undefined index: resultado in C:\xampp\htdocs\acin\envio.php on line 63